# Cannot alter column 'some_field' to be data type decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

When I try to ALTER a column of **TEXT** datatype to **DECIMAL** or vice versa, it won't. But if I alter it to **VARCHAR** first, then it can ALTER into DECIMAL. My question is, why can't we ALTER from TEXT to decimal or decimal to text directly?

```
Create Table temp
( 
    id int,
    some_field text NULL
) 

ALTER TABLE temp ALTER COLUMN some_field DECIMAL(16,2) NULL;
--Cannot alter column 'some_field' to be data type decimal(16,2).
```

Altering it to varchar:

```
ALTER TABLE temp ALTER COLUMN some_field VARCHAR NULL;
--Command(s) completed successfully.

ALTER TABLE temp ALTER COLUMN some_field DECIMAL(16,2) NULL;
--Command(s) completed successfully.
```

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: yes, we don't use these data types, i guess someone was playing around at the client. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server simply cannot convert from text to decimal. To see the implicit and explicit conversions it can do, [check the chart in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#implicit-conversions).